# Remote App doesn't work with Internet Sharing

Tags: network, wifi, appletv, vpn, airplay

I setup a VPN on my Mac mini that I'm sharing with my AppleTV via Internet Sharing.
So my AppleTV is only connected to my network via Internet Sharing.

This is my network setup (Mac mini has two ethernet ports):

```
Internet <-ethernet-> Router <-ethernet-> Mac mini <-ethernet-> AppleTV
My Router also has Wifi and that's how I connect my phone to the network.
```

From my phone I can't access the AppleTV with the remote app.
Airplay on the other hand works fine from my phone.
That seems odd to me. Do you have any idea how I can fix that?

Thanks for you support.

Dan